# What was Newton's view of theory of matter?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, history, point-particles

Did Newton believe in infinitely small particle theory of matter? Because he talks about axis of rotation, which is locus of the centers of the circles of the rotating body 
and my teacher said particle on the axis does not rotate. and i think for that they must have no size. For that, I had to consider matter made of infinitely small particles with no size at all.is my teacher wrong about particles on the axis of rotation or there is something said by newton about that concept.

Comment: Would this be better on history of science SE?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [HSM.se] SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for,but it might provide some insights:

**Personal opinion:**

I think it was just an assumption.At that time there weren't any proof's for the existence of atoms and molecules.But the concept of atom is very old.He obviously must've know the theory and also believed in it.

Something related I have found on wikipedia to show his interests in [smaller particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Newton#Optics)

In 1704, Newton published Opticks, in which he expounded his corpuscular theory of light. He considered light to be made up of extremely subtle corpuscles, that ordinary matter was made of grosser corpuscles and speculated that through a kind of alchemical transmutation "Are not gross Bodies and Light convertible into one another, ... and may not Bodies receive much of their Activity from the Particles of Light which enter their Composition?" Newton also constructed a primitive form of a frictional electrostatic generator, using a glass globe.

Like Aaron stevens says this question belongs to this [site](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)